# how to override adminhtml controller action.php in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to override in adminhtml controller `action.php`

Here is what I tried so far:

*config.xml*

```
<args>
     <modules>
          <Medma_MarketPlace before="Mage_Adminhtml">Medma_MarketPlace</Medma_MarketPlace>
     </modules>
</args>
```

My code for Medma/Marketplace/controllers/adminhtml/action.php

```
require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controller/Action.php";

class Medma_MarketPlace_Adminhtml_ActionController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_ActionController 
{
   // do something
}
```

but nothing happens. I think I'm do something wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Arvind, Please check if you have correctly wrote the config lines, args must be inside adminhtml tag as follows :

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable_Adminhtml</Mynamespace_CustomerGroupReturnable>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Hope this helps.